# Is there actually a method to disable showing admob's interstital banner after the app was closed?

Tags: android, admob

Interstitial loads in the app and is showing up after you closed the app. How to prevent that? The interstital has no methods like cancle or destroy.

Is the only solution **interstital = null;** ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure regarding a method that might be available, but you can easly prevent it.

You can call finish on the activity, if possible.

If not, just set a flag (boolean) and set it to false using onPause or onStop events, check this flag before calling show () on the interstitial.

```
if (your_fancy_new_flag)
{ 
   //show the interstitial
}
```

Comment: I call finish but it happen anyway. I think your flag solution is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Interstitial ads only show when you explicitly call `show()`.

So just don't call `show`